# iframe and Remarketing Code Madness

Tags: magento, iframe, footer

So I have nearly finished working on an a eCommerce platform with Magento and we are now running Remarketing campaigns via Google's Ad Display Network.

Now...

If you look here: http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/8859/52447256.jpg

I had placed the remarketing tag underneath my footer links and it has caused those links to be shifted on the bottom and in the center where as before it was flush and tidy on the right hand side in line with the newsletter opt-in form.

What's causing this is the iframe width. If I set '300' to '0' then its back to how it should be and perfectly in line.

Now the problem...

I placed this remarketing tag in magento and the code does not provide any iframe html code. I checked the footer by going to:

\MY WEBSITE\html\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\footer.phtml

What did I find? Barely anything lol. So now I am confused as to where this iframe was created and how to solve it. Any ideas would highly be appreciated!

Steve.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem just yesterday while working in a shitty Comarch Aurum CMS and was looking for a safe solution which wouldn't get me banned:

[Google remarketing tag - iframe height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467529/google-remarketing-tag-iframe-height-issue)

so if anyone else has this problem, the most common solution is to insert the conversion.js script tag into a hidden div:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">  </script>
</div>
```

src:
[keanrichmond.com/google-remarketing-messing-with-my-design.html](http://keanrichmond.com/google-remarketing-messing-with-my-design.html)