# Google remarketing tag - iframe height issue

Tags: css, iframe

I've noticed that Google's remarketing code inserts an iframe at the bottom of my page. The problem is that the iframe messes up my layout (it's 13px high and leaves a blank white vertical space at the bottom).

I've tried to hide it with css but it's still visible in IE9:

```
iframe[name='google_conversion_frame'] { 
    height: 0 !important; 
    line-height: 0 !important; 
    font-size: 0 !important; 
}
```

Therefore I've got two questions:

a) how to hide this iframe in IE9

b) most importantly - is it safe or can it somehow affect the functionality of this script?

Comment: You can add and try : `html body iframe[name=google_conversion_frame] { visibility:hidden; height:0 !important; }`.

Comment: Replace your CSS with display:none , does it still display?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid messing with visibility or display because I have no idea if the code will still work - kind of a stupid thing but still if anybody finds any confirmed info please type it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: What about absolute positioning it off the screen?

Comment: the problem is I don't know and I wouldn't like to get banned. After some time of digging I found a solution that seems to work (insert script in a hidden div):

http://www.keanrichmond.com/google-remarketing-messing-with-my-design.html

@Muhammad Talha Akbar and Prasanna Aarthi - you were close so please make an answer of it so we can close this question

Comment: I would avoid the hidden div wrapper workaround, since the tag assistant extension for Google chrome suggests the `Code should be placed directly above the closing <body> tag.` I think it would work just fine but its best if it fully complies with the API

Answer (score 141, accepted):

In my sites i use this code

```
iframe[name='google_conversion_frame'] { 
    height: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important; 
    line-height: 0 !important; 
    font-size: 0 !important;
    margin-top: -13px;
    float: left;
}
```

Floating the iframe allows you to use negative margin equal to the height of the body inside the iframe.

Comment: Any reason not to just `display: none !important`?

Comment: @AnthonyDiSanti because, in my tests, this not remove the 13px height generated by the script inside for all browsers.

Comment: Beautiful solution, still works 2017-1-31. Combined with https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/ that chrome console debugger code to find overflowing elements, a perfect solution, thanks

Comment: Is there a reason we're not just using `iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"] { display: none; }`? Would that break the tracking?

Comment: Hiding an iframe is very "hacky". This is needed if a browser has JS disabled, many browsers doesn't run code if is in a hidden iframe.

Answer (score 31):

Other way around (mentioned in the comments above) is to insert the conversion.js script tag into a hidden div:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">  </script>
</div>
```

src: http://keanrichmond.com/google-remarketing-messing-with-my-design.html

Comment: Same solution and confirmation that there are no side-effects was also proposed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939653/google-adwords-remove-iframe-added-by-tracking-conversion-code

Comment: This may actually stop some browsers loading the tracking iframe, so I'd suggest testing this across all the common browsers before deploying to a live site.

Comment: Google do a lot of checking for simulated fake data.  I wouldn't be suprised if google filtered out results when the iframe is hidden.  There is a reason they put the iframe there.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. The good solution was to add a line in the google remarketing tag.

```
    var google_conversion_format = 3;
```

The tag before modification :

```
<!-- Code Google de la balise de remarketing -->
<script type="text/javascript">/* 
<![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 10xxxxxxxx;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
<noscript><div style="display:inline;"><img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/10xxxxxxxx/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/></div></noscript>
```

The tag after modification :

```
<!-- Code Google de la balise de remarketing -->
<script type="text/javascript">/* 
<![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 10xxxxxxxx;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;

var google_conversion_format = 3; /* ADD THIS LINE TO RESOLVE YOUR PROBLEM */

/* ]]> */
```

Comment: This worked great. Hopefully google doesn't change anything now.

Comment: Worked on one site for me but not my other site.. What the heck Google?

Answer (score 17):

DO NOT USE THOSE OVERLY COMPLICATED ANSWERS. Simply use `position:fixed;` on that element to take it out of the document flow.

Like this:

```
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"]{
    position:fixed;
}
```

That's it! You keep all original functionality AND you don't have to worry about API changes.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any downside to just setting the iframe to be absolute positioning.

```css
iframe[name='google_conversion_frame'] {
    position: absolute;     
    bottom: 0;
}
```

less code, no !important's and no display: none

Answer (score 2):

Here is my super simple minified solution:

```css
/* Hide AdWords Remarketing iFrame */
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"]{display:block; height:0;}
```

I tested and it works in Chrome, FireFox, and IE 10.

There are several ways to hide it of course, but why not have another option.

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"] {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added "border: none;" as my site auto inserted a border that showed a colour even when collapsed.

```css
/* Hide AdWords Remarketing iFrame */
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"] {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used css to set the height and width to zero. Wrapped the conversion.js file around a div with an id and set its child iframe width and height to 0.

```
<div id="googleiframe">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
#googleiframe iframe{height:0;width:0;}
 </style>
```

You can set the style in the main css file.